# Custon UISlider with non rectangular area

Tags: iphone

I would like to customize my UISlider like this screenshot :

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/7707/sliderp.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/7707/sliderp.png)

I'm using setMinimumTrackImage and setMaximumTrackImage method with a non strechable image but it doesn't work.

The image is stretched and proportion are kept.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Thierry

Answer (score 3):

You might try setting invisible images for both minimumTrackImage and maximumTrackImage to transparent, and then sticking a UIImageView behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the frame size of your slider, all your are changing are the values

```
UISlider *customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X,Y,Width,Heigth)];
```

I hope this helps